# Wordpress Site Not Updating Even After Clearing Cache

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

My wordpress blog isn't showing updates even after clearing the cache, multiple times. I discovered my blog (hosted with hostgator) had the endurance cache plugin installed in the "must use" plugins.

I did some googling, renamed the file with a .old extension, created a new blank file with the same name and uploaded to the folder that previously had the .php file.

I'm using WP Super Cache as my caching plugin now, the problem is, no matter how many times I clear the cache, my website is still showing a cached version from two days ago (July 20th).

I update my blog often, about 4-8 times per day with new posts, and I need the cache to be cleared every time I publish a new post.

Yes if I hard refresh ctrl + f5 everything displays as it should, but when checking in different browsers I still see the cached version of my site from days ago.

I've been googling non-stop for the past 3 days trying to find a fix but nothing I do seems to be working.

I even manually deleted everything in the "cache" folder from my server. I don't know what else to do anymore.

I've done everything I could think of to possibly do, so I decided to post here to see if anyone has some extra suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Download the copy for the file from `mu-plugins` folder and remove the file in its entirety. Note that this will remove the plugin but since you are already using wp-super-cache so it should be ok.

Comment: Hope this helps? https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/css-stylesheet-not-updating-on-wordpress-website/

Comment: @FahamShaikh I've already done that, I just gave up and removed both caching plugins (endurance and wp super cache) my website still doesn't show any updates.

WPZA I'm not talking about updates to CSS, I mean I want the entire site to show my new posts when I publish them, instantly. I don't mind slow loading times or anything, I just want my new posts to show up.

Is there anyway to stop wordpress from caching my site across ALL browsers?

Comment: @A.Clarke Can you check your cpanel to ensure varnish or other similar caching mechanism is not already turned on.

Comment: @FahamShaikh I double and triple checked  everything, I disabled and deleted every caching plugin, even turned off the wp cache by editing the wp-config file, nothing seems to be working. Updates only show in the backend. I think I give up, it has been 4 days and nothing works.